# Calculate new 2D vector translated perpendicularly from initial vector

Tags: math, vector, trigonometry

I have a vector in 2D that is defined by two sets of points, (x1, y1) and (x2, y2). I need to calculate a new vector that is translated perpendicularly by H distance.

For example if my points are (0, 0) and (0, 10) a perpendicular translation of H=5 would result in a new vector (5, 0) and (5, 10).

I am trying to find a more generic formula. I know I should probably use the heading (or azimuth) angle. That is the angle from the y axis clockwise to my vector. But I can not wrap my head around the trig.

Ideally I would like to have H > 0 be a right translation and H < 0 a left translation (assuming standing at x1/y1 looking at x2/y2).

Comment: To clarify: should a translation of (0,0) and (1,1) by 2 result in (2,0), (3,1), or something like (-2,2), (-1, 3)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about trigonometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the two endpoints of you line segment, A=(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) and B=(x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>). (Note that *vectors* and *line segments* are not the same thing.)

Calculate the vector: v = B-A = (x<sub>2</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>)

Calculate its magnitude: |v| = sqrt(v<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>  +v<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>)

Normalize it (that is, change its magnitude to one, leaving its direction unchanged): v' = v/|v| = (v<sub>1</sub>/|v|, v<sub>2</sub>/|v|)

Rotate it 90 degrees clockwise: v'' = (v'<sub>2</sub>, -v'<sub>1</sub>)

Multiply it by H: z = Hv'' = (Hv''<sub>1</sub>, Hv''<sub>2</sub>)

Add that to your two endpoints: A' = A+z = (x<sub>1</sub>+z<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>+z<sub>2</sub>) B'= B+z = (x<sub>2</sub>+z<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>+z<sub>2</sub>)

The subscripts may look a little confusing. That's because you and I are using different conventions: You are using letters for dimensions and subscripts for points; I am doing it the other way around. Ordinarily I try to use the language of the person whose question I'm trying to answer, but in this case your convention gets confusing when there are several points involved. If it's really unclear, I can try to rewrite it.

Comment: OMG thank you! As soon as I saw your X/Y and sign flip it clued into me. I was trying to formulate it using the angle between Y axis and my vector and this was so much easier.